# Design Stable IIR Filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

I need to design a stable IIR filter in MATLAB.  Specifically, I am trying to use a butterworth filter to correct the phase and gain of a 2 pole RC filter:

```
d = fdesign.arbmagnphase('n,f,h', n, f, h); 
myFilter = design(d,'iir','butter');
```

The butterworth part is not really important, there are several options to choose from.  Is it possible to constrain MATLAB to produce an IIR filter that is stable?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a better way? Anyway to have a stable system you just need to have the poles inside the unit circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working through some possible solutions, we figured out it would be easier to design argitrary magnitude and group delay separately in MATLAB:

```
fdesign.arbmag
fdesign.arbgrpdelay
```